# Toupie à / de... sur main (« hand / fidget spinner ») ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, usage, prépositions, compléments

Le [*fidget / hand spinner*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidget_spinner#cite_note-1) est un « petit gadget composé d'un roulement central entouré d'un nombre variable de branches qu'on fait tourner en le tenant dans une main » note [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=SPINNER&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) qui consigne *toupie de main* et *toupie à main*, qu'on a trouvé respectivement dans un article de [*La Presse*](http://www.lapresse.ca/le-soleil/actualites/education/201705/16/01-5098660-le-hand-spinner-vraiment-efficace.php) et dans [*Le Figaro*](http://www.lefigaro.fr/societes/2017/05/16/20005-20170516ARTFIG00017-le-spinner-nouveau-phenomene-mondial-des-cours-de-recre.php). L'article *Wikipédia* contient une référence littérale à la « toupie à tripoter » basée sur la traduction de [*fidget*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/fidget) par *Collins* en ligne. Par ailleurs on sait déjà que la [*toupie*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toupie) « se maintient en équilibre quand on lui imprime un mouvement de rotation à la main [...] » (TLFi) etc. ; qu'il y a une certaine complémentarité dans l'emploi des prépositions ; qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un emploi pour marquer l'appartenance.

---

- Dans *toupie à main*, la préposition [**à**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) sert-elle de la même
  manière que dans le syntagme *frein à main*, c'est-à-dire pour
  introduire la *source d'énergie* ; sinon sur quelle fonction de la
  préposition s'appuie-t-on ; y a-t-il pléonasme ?
- Dans *toupie de main*, de quel genre de détermination s'agit-il,
  d'un truc spatial, de l'origine, d'une dénomination : comment est
  utilisée la préposition [**de**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) dans ce cas ; cette fonction
  créé-t-elle un « format » comme avec [*de poche*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/poche/61899/locution?q=de%20poche#164840) ; y a-t-il pléonasme ?
- Un usage, un prototype, s'impose-t-il et que comprendrait-on de *toupie [sur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sur)
  main* ; au passage sait-on si un néologisme existe et si oui lequel ?

Comment: Vu comment l'objet est utilisé, j'aurais parlé de _doigts_ plutôt que de _main_.

Comment: Quelle est la question ? Si c'est de savoir s'il y a déjà une expression consacrée, Je ne crois pas. C'est quelque chose de très récent. Je n'ai vu que des anglicismes. Si c'est de savoir ce qu'il faudrait dire. Vos 2 propositions me semblent valides. Oserai-je ajouter *toupie pour main/doigt* si on veut dire que c'est pour s'occuper les mains. Bof. Je viens aussi de voir *toupie de doigts*. Si c'est pour trouver une nouvelle expression. Je ne m'y risquerai pas. La mode s'éteindra peut-être avant qu'elle n'arrive :) Pour le pléonasme, il y a les toupies à bois.

Comment: @jcm69 Merci, bien je me demande quelle préposition réalise le mieux l'apport souhaité et comment, mais votre commentaire peut facilement valoir réponse. Et qu'est-ce qu'une _toupie à bois_ ? J'ai vu _toupie d'Allemagne_ mais avec l'idée d'origine le choix de préposition est assez clair. Vous comme mouviciel traitez des doigts, c'est une bonne précision. La préposition _pour_ c'est aussi intéressant. Comme je dis souvent, n'hésitez pas à répondre. Merci.

Comment: Extrait du web: La fraiseuse horizontale ou toupie à bois réalise des opérations d'usinage très précises et localisées sur des éléments en bois, même encombrants, grâce aux dimensions importantes de sa table d'accueil et à la variété de sa découpe. Sinon, tapez simplement toupie dans wikipédia, il y en a 6. C'est bizarre, j'ai l'impression que toutes pourraient faire l'affaire mais aucune ne me satisfait pleinement. Du coup, je cherche, je cherche et je vais finir par en acheter une pour me calmer ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Toupie à main.
Pour faire une toupie de main, il faudrait couper une main, la faire geler et la faire tourner autour d'un doigt levé.